# How do i install an previous of flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pip, python-3.6

I want to install an older version of flask and can't figure out how to do that and I am using an Linux machine. I checked other questions about how to determine the version of flask but they only return the version of flask and even after trying different methods I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+old+version+package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install flask==<VERSION>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pip documentation it looks like you can do that by typing:

```
pip install packagename == 1.4
```

in this case you would type pip install flask==(the version you want)